# Set properties from much controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer, windows-forms-designer

I want to change some properties of control.
I don't know how to explain it. So let me explain with a snippet of code:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(DateTimePicker))
    {
        (control as DateTimePicker).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        (control as DateTimePicker).CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yy  |  HH:mm";
    }

    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
    {
        foreach (Control subControl in control.Controls)
        {
            subControl.Name = control.Name + subControl.Name;
        }
    }

    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
    {
        control.Name = LabelNameCreate(control.Text);
    }
}
```

will be more changes like these, but **how can i save these** ?

I want run the code then my project would take the form of new.

Is there any method or components for create designer.cs for running forms ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can multi select them all in the designer.  Click on one, hold the control key, and click on the rest.  Then set the properties in the Properties window.  It should change all of them.  Then save your changes.

If that doesn't work, because there are too many, I think your only alternative is to edit the  Designer.CS file directly.  If it were my problem, I would list all the controls in a column in an Excel Spreadsheet, then use a concatenate function to write the C# I want placed in the Designer.CS file.  Then paste that it in.  Save and close the file.

Comment: i have 60 page with different z-index how can click control at bottom

Comment: If you right click, it will pop a menu, and all of the controls under the mouse will be in the list to select.

Comment: it can select only showing one, all panel is fill docked and they are same location and size.I can not to tell how works the project. I am using [Send to Back] and [Bring to Front] buttons to editing these. on code running all panel will be hiding except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be the Form_Load as i think, but thats not a clean solution. Try doing it in the designer manually. Create one element and give it the wanted propertys. Then Copy and paste it

Comment: This code is already running, but each program is opened again. it takes about 3 seconds.